# sql table row - column conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have following table:

[image]

How to convert the above table into below structure? I tried using pivot table but couldn't       get it to work.

[image]

Comment: SQL is just the **query language** - not a database product. For stuff like this, we really need to know what **concrete database PRODUCT** you're using - MySQL? Postgres? Oracle? IBM DB2? SQL Server? Something else?? Please update your tags accordingly

Comment: I am working on SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have to look up [SQL PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21b41/2)

And the code:

```
SELECT    * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT    Prodname, 
              pcode, 
              Biiledamt
    FROM      Product
) p
PIVOT 
(
    SUM    (Biiledamt)
    FOR    Prodname IN ([Prod1],[Prod2],[Prod3],[Prod4])
)   AS pvt
```

If you do not know beforehand the columns then you can [check this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21b41/4) which dynamically generates the columns to use.

The code for that is:

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',[' + Prodname +']'
            FROM Product c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


SET @query = 
'    SELECT    * 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT    Prodname, 
                  pcode, 
                  Biiledamt
        FROM      Product
    ) p
    PIVOT 
    (
        SUM    (Biiledamt)
        FOR    Prodname IN (' + @cols + ')
    )   AS pvt
'


EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Can you give a solution for that?